# Update php sessions value when a new input is keyed

Tags: php, session

I am trying to change the session value $item['qty'] immediately when a new input is keyed. How do I do it without submitting a form?

```
                <div id="cartdesc">
                    <p id="cartitemname"> ' . $item["name"] . ' </p>
                    <p>Quantity: <input type="number" step="1" min="1" value="' . $item["qty"] . '"> </p> //this is the line of concerned!!
                    <p>Size: ' . $item["size"] . ' </p>
                    <p>Price:$ ' . $item["price"] . ' </p>
                    <p>Item total price $ ' . number_format($item["qty"] * $item["price"], 2) . ' </p>
                    <a href="cart.php?action=remove&code=' . $key . '" class="btnRemoveAction"><img id="deletebtn"  src="res/istockphoto-928418914-170667a.jpg" alt="Remove Item" /></a>

                </div>
```

Comment: (1) use JS `onkeyup` event to trigger an ajax calling a PHP which updates the field value (or if you will move the cursor to another field, then you may use onchange event) (2) strictly speaking it is not a session-variable like `$_SESSION["xxxx"]` (which you tagged)

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving an answer based on @KenLee's suggestion.

The problem here comes is with picking up the right event with JavaScript (jQuery):

Here's a solution for you:

```
<input id="itemsNo" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="' . $item["qty"] . '">
```

jQuery (3.4.1):

```
$("input[type='number']").bind("input", function() {
    console.log("I am executed")
    //If using jQuery to set session variables and you want it to be the value 
    //of this input just get its value with .val() and store it in the variable 
    //after it you would be able to assign that value to the session
    //or write AJAX call
});
```

So, as you can see, here whether you click onto input and enter the number or click on arrows, you will get `"I am executed"` inside of the console everytime.

Next thing, I don't see a reason why would you set the SESSION variable within PHP file while you're able to do so with jQuery like this:

```
localStorage['yourSESSIONVariable'] = "SomeValue";
```

or you could try using HTML5s sessionStorage it lasts for the duration on the page session. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("yourSESSIONVariable", "SomeValue");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage

Anyways, if you still need and want to set SESSION value with PHP, here's a reference for jQuery Ajax you can go check here:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/